# Selecting default option value with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to select a default select option based on one of the property with which I'm populating my select option.

This code is copied straight from [@rneimeyer's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ZP79w/). I did tweak it to do what I wanted to do.

So, I have choices as my observableArray.

```
var choices = [
    { id: 1, name: "one", choice: false },
    { id: 2, name: "two", choice: true },
    { id: 3, name: "three", choice: false }
    ];

function ViewModel(choices, choice) {
   this.choices = ko.observableArray(choices);
};
```

The difference between rneimeyer's fiddle and mine is that I have `choice` property added on my object inside the observableArray instead of having a separate observable for the option that we want to be default.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shriek/ZxLV7/) on my attempt.

Now I'm checking in my select element tag whether the `choice` attribute is true or not. And if it is then I want to set the `name` to the `value` attribute so that it becomes the default.

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, optionsText: 'name', value: choice"></select>
```

I've tested this with [simple data model in my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybanm/) here as well which is working just as I wanted.

I guess what my real query is how to check `choice` property in the data-bind. I see that `optionText` is being able to access the `name` property just fine. Not sure why it isn't same for `choice` property in `value` attribute.

Comment: `The difference between rneimeyer's fiddle and mine is that I have choice property added on my object inside the observableArray instead of having a separate observable for the option that we want to be default.` Why? What's wrong with the other approach? What problem are you trying to solve by doing it like this?

Comment: The difference is how the data is being passed to me by the service. The service is giving me all the information in one chunk rather than have an object that only has the default option.

Comment: So? When you get the data from your service, you run through it and pull out the one that has `choice === true` and put it in your `selectedOption` observable. As it currently stands, it's not going to work because `choice` isn't an observable anyway and you have the problem that you can't change `choice` on two entries at once so you will have a situation where either two options are chosen or no options are chosen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I might have misdirected to some people. Also, I apologize for not mentioning the version that I'm using. I'm currently using Knockout 3.0.0 (you'll see why this is important later)

Also, just to note that I'm not saying @XGreen's method is wrong but that wasn't exactly what I was looking for and this might be due to my poor explanation.

Let me first try to clarify what I was trying to accomplish. 
First of all, I will be having an array of object with the information for the options.

```
[
 { id: 1, name: "one", choice: false },
 { id: 2, name: "two", choice: true },
 { id: 3, name: "three", choice: false }
]
```

Now, what I wanted to do was to data-bind select option to that array with choice true being the default selected one.

I'm not intending to create any extra observable except the array itself which is going to be an observableArray.

After much research I finally found `optionsAfterRender` attribute for `options` property in [Knockout's Docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, 
                   optionsValue: 'name',
                   optionsAfterRender: $root.selectDefault">
</select>
```

So what optionsAfterRender really does is, on each array element it calls custom function which I've set to check if the `choice` is true or not and make the value of select option that which has the true.

Do note that `ko.applyBindingsToNode` *does not* work on version 2.2.0 which I had in my original fiddle.

```
function ViewModel(choices) {
   this.choices = ko.observableArray(choices);
    this.selectDefault = function(option,item){
        if(item.choice){
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(option.parentElement, {value: item.name}, item);
        }
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(choices));
```

And here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxLV7/) for it.

Comment: Nice work. Just remember that in your solution you will always have the last element in your collection that it's choice property is true as your default value. If you only have one item at all times that is true that doesn't matter but on larger collections and many true items this could be potentially a wasteful iteration as you could have given up looking after finding the first true item

Answer (score 4):

Ok If I understand you want to set the true choice as your default selected value.

First you need to involve `id` in your drop down so it becomes the value of the options as we will filter our collection based on that unique `id`

```
<select data-bind="options: choices, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id',  value: selectedChoice"></select>
```

As you see now you need to create a new observable called `selectedChoice` and we are going to populate that observable with the choice that is true using a computed.

```
var choices = [
    { id: 1, name: "one", choice: false },
    { id: 2, name: "two", choice: true },
    { id: 3, name: "three", choice: false }
    ];

function ViewModel(choices) {
   var self = this;
   self.choices = ko.observableArray(choices);
   self.trueChoice = ko.computed(function(){
       return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.choices(), function(item){
           return item.choice === true;
       });
    });
    self.selectedChoice = ko.observable(self.trueChoice().id);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(choices));
```

the new computed property `trueChoice` uses the `arrayFirst` method in order to return the first item in your choices collection that has its choice property set to true.

Now that we have our true choice all we have to do is to set the selected value of the dropdown aka `selectedChoice` to be the id of that true choice so the item becomes selected in the drop down.

[Here is also a working fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/uJsn4/)

Comment: You're right on needing `optionsValue`. That was crucial part of this piece but I still don't intend to create observable on my VM just to do a simple check on the select options.

Answer (score 3):

Added a Gist that disabled the first option in a select drop down list, and work nicely with KO's `optionsCaption` binding, using a `optionsDisableDefault` binding:

https://gist.github.com/garrypas/d2e72a54162787aca345e9ce35713f1f

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="value: MyValueField,
    options:OptionsList,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsCaption: 'Select an option',
    optionsDisableDefault: true">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a computed that holds the selected items

```
self.selected_options = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        return self.choices.filter(function(item){ return item.choice });
    },
    write: function(value) {
        self.choices.forEach(function(item) { item.choice = value.indexOf(item) > 0;});
    }
})
```

Then bind to that as the selected options.